# How can we develop a test method in Java (& Selenium Webdriver), for tracking 'a reset e-mail Notification', without verifying in mailbox?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am developing UI Automation for testing a web app and currently confronted with, writing a test method to track if an email notification has been sent to a recipient. BUT, the challenge here is NOT to wait for some time and then checking in the recipient's mail box, but to be able to track the outgoing request for verification on the Web App itself.

Here is my current Code checking if mail URL is there or not after triggering the email notification.:

```
@Test
public void chkEmailNotif() {

    try {

        PO.clickEmailUrl(); //PO is a page object class
        assertTrue(PO.MailFrameSeen());
        PO.clickYes();
        System.out.println(" Clicked on Yes button of the Mail frame Box ");
        assertFalse(!PO.isMailurlSeen());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println ("Catched exception e" + e )
        }

    }
```

Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Mock the mailbox and check the message is sent. Set the configuration to use the mock or the real mailbox in a file that changes with the environment.

Comment: Thanks Andres, will try on that suggestion and update the result here.

Comment: Hi Andres, can you please guide me in finding any examples for achieving this (ie., Mocking a mail box and checking the mail content ) please?